# Issues with setTimeout with Javascript in HTML5 canvas on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, html, function, drag

I'm experimenting with a script and trying to adopt use for an iOS device. Since there would no way to use an onmousemove event, I want to use something that would simulate touching and dragging. The easiest way I came up with doing this is using a timer to always render the draw effect I have with the current mouse position only if it has been toggled first by using onmousedown, and untoggled by using onmouseup.

I'd expect the timeCount function to be triggered if I just call it outside of any function, but it doesn't, so first I check if it's null inside the onmousedown event, and if it is, call timedCount.

timeCount is called, and even though I have the setTimeout defined, it only calls timeCount one additional time, and that's it. So that's my first problem.

Secondly, how would I capture my current touch point (assuming the users finger is somewhere else on the screen) without an event? Or do I need an event? Which one?

Code is as follows. It's an edited example from http://html5demos.com/canvas-grad:

```
<canvas height="600" width="600"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],

ctx = null,
grad = null,
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
color = 255;
var toggleDraw = 0;
var timer = null;



if (canvas.getContext('2d')) {

  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  ctx.save();
  // Create radial gradient
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,0,0,0,600); 
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
  grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(' + color + ', ' + color + ', ' + color + ')');

  // assign gradients to fill
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;

  // draw 600x600 fill
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
  ctx.save();

}
```

canvas.onmousedown = function (event) {
    toggleDraw = 1;
    if(timer == null){
        timedCount();
    }
};

canvas.onmouseup = function (event) {
    toggleDraw = 0;
};

function timedCount(){

```
if(toggleDraw == 1){

    alert("yes");

    var width = window.innerWidth, 
    height = window.innerHeight, 
    x = event.clientX, 
    y = event.clientY,
    rx = 600 * x / width,
    ry = 600 * y / height;

    var xc = ~~(256 * x / width);
    var yc = ~~(256 * y / height);

    grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(rx, ry, 0, rx, ry, 600); 
    grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
    grad.addColorStop(1, ['rgb(', xc, ', ', (255 - xc), ', ', yc, ')'].join(''));

    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);

}

timer=setTimeout("timedCount()",50);
```

}

I've also tried an alternative of using setInterval on the canvas mouse events and removing the setTimeout in the timeCount function, but the timeCount function is not called at all:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function (event) {
    toggleDraw = 1;
    timer=setInterval("timedCount()",50);
};

canvas.onmouseup = function (event) {
    toggleDraw = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
};
```

**Edit: Even with this, I cannot get it to work:**

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = null,
    grad = null,
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    color = 255;

    if (canvas.getContext('2d')) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        ctx.save();
        // Create radial gradient
        grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,0,0,0,600); 
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
        grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(' + color + ', ' + color + ', ' + color + ')');

        // assign gradients to fill
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;

        // draw 600x600 fill
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
        ctx.save();

        canvas.ontouchmove = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var width = window.innerWidth, 
            height = window.innerHeight, 
            x = event.clientX, 
            y = event.clientY,
            rx = 600 * x / width,
            ry = 600 * y / height;

            var xc = ~~(256 * x / width);
            var yc = ~~(256 * y / height);

            grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(rx, ry, 0, rx, ry, 600); 
            grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
            grad.addColorStop(1, ['rgb(', xc, ', ', (255 - xc), ', ', yc, ')'].join(''));
            // ctx.restore();
            ctx.fillStyle = grad;
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
            // ctx.save();
        };
    }
    </script>
```

**Okay, here is the working script!!**

It is vital to use Apples touch API, and keep track of the touch you want to use:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = null,
    grad = null,
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    color = 255;

    if (canvas.getContext('2d')) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        ctx.save();
        // Create radial gradient
        grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,0,0,0,600); 
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
        grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(' + color + ', ' + color + ', ' + color + ')');

        // assign gradients to fill
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;

        // draw 600x600 fill
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
        ctx.save();


    }

    canvas.ontouchmove = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(event.touches.length == 1){
            var touch = event.touches[0];
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth, 
        height = window.innerHeight, 
        //x = event.clientX, 
        //y = event.clientY,
        x = touch.pageX;
        y = touch.pageY;

        rx = 600 * x / width,
        ry = 600 * y / height;

        var xc = ~~(256 * x / width);
        var yc = ~~(256 * y / height);

        grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(rx, ry, 0, rx, ry, 600); 
        grad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
        grad.addColorStop(1, ['rgb(', xc, ', ', (255 - xc), ', ', yc, ')'].join(''));
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS all mouse events fire at once, when the touch is finished.  Which probably is not what you want.

Use `ontouchdown`, `ontouchmove` and `ontouchup` events instead.

Also, in `ontouchmove`, you need to prevent the default behavior so the page doesn't start scrolling.

```
canvas.ontouchmove = function(e) {
  // your code here
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced my event functions with just             canvas.ontouchmove = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.timedCount();
            } without intervals, but timeCount doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: `event.timedCount();`? that shouldn't exist... Try somehting simpler to start.  Make the body of your event handler simply `alert('omg it works')` and see if the function is being called at all.  One problem at a time here :)

Comment: Actually I think it's because I'm not specifying a touch in the list of touches.. I"ll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle touch specific events

1. touchstart: Happens every time a finger is placed on the screen
2. touchend: Happens every time a finger is removed from the screen
3. touchmove: Happens as a finger already placed on the screen is moved across the screen

See link http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

```
node.ontouchstart = function(evt){
  console.log(evt.pageX + "/" + evt.pageY);
}
```